# Do I need to add an index on a table with one row?

Tags: database-design

I'm creating a parameter table in our database.  This table will have 1 row with values that are environment specific (production, development, etc).

Is there any reason why I should define an index on this table?

**Update**
This table is a parameter table which will be used to drive our job queue system.  The table will be defined like this:

```
QueuePrm
  LogLvl    integer
  ShowMs    boolean
  Restart   boolean
```

This table will only ever have 1 row.  No other table in our system will reference it.

Comment: I agree that at the very least you need to declare a primary key in order to use this information with other table relationships. A simple (PK) declaration will do the trick for you.

Comment: Double checking - do you mean one *Row* or one *Column*?

Comment: Could you spell out the DDL for this table?  It sounds like this is a table with 1 row and N columns, one column for each environment. This sounds wrong to begin with - if you have another env, then you need to alter the table and corresponding code?

Comment: Are you unable to create the table without one or is there some other reason to ask?

Comment: Why would you ever want to join anything on a one-row table? And even if you would, any join condition would be redundant, you'd just tack the single row onto every result set row. No need for an index.

Comment: The real question is why don't you have a key-value-pair table instead? Each of your fields could be represented as an integer or a string in the Value column.

Comment: @pdr I'm not a fan of the inner-platform anti-pattern.

Comment: @briddums: I don't see the connection. It's not about making your application infinitely extensible, although there's no question that adding a row will be easier than adding a column, as your application expands. The reason for using key-values is that it's much quicker to access a single value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, you do not need an index for a one-row table, nor do you need a primary key.  The only purpose of an index is to speed certain operations by making it possible to locate a row without reading the entire table.

Many relational database implementations require indexes for foreign-key or uniqueness constraints (including primary keys).  That is not a logical necessity.  It is done because an index will be desired in almost all cases, and it isn't worth the trouble to support these constraints without an index.  When a table is so small that an index isn't useful, the index doesn't cost much.

Comment: Some RDBMS will create their own in the background anyway.

Comment: +1.  With a single row table, he shouldnt need to access it in queries via joins anyways.  The values in the table could be loaded once when the page is loaded or when the client starts, and the values then used in queries directly.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

While it looks like there is no need now, tables like this become filled with values as the system progressively ages.  You might insist on multiple tables for keeping different parameters segregated, but eventually all tables like this expand.

It is best to start with a key, descriptive of the purpose if possible.  Future maintenance staff appreciate understandable names.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, the primary key of the table (you DO have a PK identifier, yes?) should have an index, also created as the clustered index by default in MS SQL Server.

If you have any secondary keys (such as a 'name' identifier column) that will be a selection criterion, index it as well.

Comment: Why would I add a primary key on a table that will only have one row?

Comment: For future expansion - there could very well be a situation where another table needs a foreign key reference to that row, or maybe a second or third row becomes added for additional configuration scenarios, or you want to delete the existing row and add a new one you then have an identifier to associate with it.

Comment: Would it really be that hard to add another column, index, PK to a table that isn't referenced by any other table until you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a one-row table with many columns, wouldn't it be neater to design it with many rows instead?
Like

```
ParamName | Value
------------------
LogLevel  | 5
BuildNr   | 3.0.9
ErrorMail | error@example.tld
```

Here ParamName will be the Primary Key.

This has the added effect that when you need to add more parameters, you can just `INSERT` them without having to update your tables and possibly your SQL queries.